# how can I change highlight text color for only a react component?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, jsx, highlight

I am using react and want to change text highlight color.
First I went for a working solution:

Highlight.css

```
    ::selection {
      background:#fbc308;
      color: black
    }
```

somecomponent.tsx

```
import './highlight.css'
```

However, it changes text highlight color for every elements, which is not I want.
And,

```
<div style={{"::selection" : {
      background:"#fbc308",
      color: "black"}}}><p>Something</p></div>
```

didn't work (error)

So, I went for:

```
.somecomponent p::selection {
   ...style
 }
```

But however it only changes p elements. I want to change all text highlight color in a component.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to replace `.somecomponent p::selection` with `.somecomponent *::selection` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for Eduard's answer, I resolved it by

```
.somecomponent *::selection
```